# Use of track by in ngFor Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am not understanding the use of `track by` function in Angular 2. I have read many blogs but they provide the same answer that `track by` improves performance. In every blog `track by` function returns index of element. What is its use? Can we return any other value than index of element? If yes, how can we use that returned value?

Comment: What value do you mean?

Comment: Grammar changes, make the text flow better.